# ngx-datatable toggling group is not working

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am using `"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^17.0.0"` where I'd like to be able to group rows and toggle them.

I also want to use the table "normally" which means that I need to switch between grouped and ungrouped (normal).

This is the selection with the prop `groupBy`:

```
    <mat-form-field style="margin-left: 15px">
      <mat-select placeholder="Gruppieren nach..." [(value)]="groupBy">
        <mat-option [value]="null" (click)="table.groupedRows = null; loadRows()">Nicht gruppieren</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let column of columns" [value]="column.prop" (click)="loadRows()">
          {{ column.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is the group header:

```
 <ngx-datatable-group-header *ngIf="groupBy" [rowHeight]="50" >
      <ng-template let-group="group" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-group-header-template>
        <div (click)="toggleExpandGroup(group)" >
          <b [class.datatable-icon-right]="!expanded" [class.datatable-icon-down]="expanded">
            {{ group.key + ': '+ group.value?.length }}
          </b>
       </div>
     </ng-template>
 </ngx-datatable-group-header>
```

The `*ngIf="groupBy"` in the group header seems to destroy the `toggleExpandGroup(group)` when `groupBy`changes from null | undefined to a specific column. It cannot be toggled anymore. If I remove it it works. But then always in "normal" view the group header is shown. It is contradictionary.

I do not understand why it behaves like that. Is there another way how I can switch from grouped to normal and back? If you need more code please let me know it.

Thank you for your help in advance.